# How to find data from one table which don't exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables, as given below. How can I check which data_entry's information are not in the task_detail table.

```
data_entry
+----+----------+----------+
| id | firstname| lastname |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Anil     | Chaudhari|
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  | Sunil    | Chaudhari|
+----+----------+----------+
| 3  | Pranil   | Chaudhari|
+----+------+--------------+

task_detail
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| id | de_id | field_name   | amount |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| 1  | 1     | firstname    | 0.1    |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| 2  | 1     | lastname     | 0.1    |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

I just want

```
data_entry
+----+----------+----------+
| id | firstname|lastnamer |
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  | Sunil    | Chaudhari|
+----+----------+----------+
| 3  | Pranil   | Chaudhari|
+----+------+--------------+
```

Comment: [Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM data_entry 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT  de_id FROM task_detail)
```

Comment: @Jain is right, Sorry by mistake I had taken id instead of de_id.

Comment: one up for you bro :)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases joins are faster than sub queries ref: [sql join vs sub query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query), so you can also use left join:

```
select de.* from data_entry de left join task_detail td on td.de_id = de.id where td.id is null
```

Comment: @AnilChaudhari absolute pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM data_entry WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT de_id FROM task_detail)
```

Using left join

```
SELECT de.* FROM data_entry de LEFT JOIN task_detail td ON de.id=td.de_id WHERE td.field_name IS NULL
```

Comment: @AnilChaudhari accept j19 answer, He gave it first. But first you should run both queries and check which one is fast on your tables. And do share the results. :)

Comment: Obviously ..  joins are faster than subquiries.  I have 6k and 40k records respectively and join's execution time is faster than subqueries..  I have tested in my SQLyog..

Comment: How about using NOT EXISTS?? @Jain

Comment: @J19  Have a look at ....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193704/how-to-find-data-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another-table/34194373#34194373

Comment: @AnilChaudhari Ya bro, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
SELECT * FROM data_entry 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM task_detail WHERE de_id=data_entry.id)
```

Comment: @Anil Chaudhari Check this one also

Comment: Using Subqueries    : Total results 1464  Showing rows 0 - 24 (1464 total, Query took 0.0170 seconds.)                                                                                              Using Left Join :   Total results 1464 Showing rows 0 - 24 (1464 total, Query took 0.0020 seconds.)                                                                     Using NOT EXISTS : Showing rows 0 - 24 (1464 total, Query took 0.2390 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from data_entry t1 join data_entry t2 on t1.id = t2.de_id where t1.id !=  t2.de_id
```